# .htaccess redirect all urls containing a specific directory name

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to forward all urls that contain a specific directory name to a file.  The directory name can be anywhere within the url as we are running many different url structures. Below are a few examples.

```
/name1/font/test/test1
/folder/name2/font/test/test1
/another/folder/name3/font/test/test1
```

these all need to forward to

```
/name/index.php?type=test&src=test1
```

I have tried the following but I am not very skilled in rewrite rules

```
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-])/font/([_0-9a-zA-Z-])/([_0-9a-zA-Z-])$ $1/index.php?type=$2&src=$3 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I put the numbers in the wrong place.  I am looking for the /font/

Comment: As per [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283057/mod-rewrite-questions-getting-migrated-to-sf) and [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283033/are-htaccess-questions-ever-on-topic-at-so) this question is not at all off-topic for SO so close vote is wrong. This has been discussed again and again and it has been settled already that most of the rewrite rules are created and maintained by developers of the web applications/frameworks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this rule:

```
RewriteRule (?:^|/)([\w-]+)/font/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1/index.php?type=$2&src=$3 [NC,QSA,L]
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?:^|/)`: Match `^` or `/`
- `([\w-]+)`: Match 1+ word or `-` characters, capture this in `$1`
- `/font/`: Match `/font/`
- `([\w-]+): Match 1+ word or` -`characters, capture this in`$2`
- `/`: Match a `/`.
- `([\w-]+)`: Match 1+ word or `-` characters, capture this in `$1`
- `/?$`: Match an optional `/` before end

**Flags Used are:**

- `NC`: Ignore case
- `L`: Last Rule
- `QSA`: Query string append

Comment: name changes.  I need to pull the the name and place it before the index